# Get docker IP address from Image name

Tags: docker

I have a running MySQL Container:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
e9b37fc68787        mysql               "docker-entrypoint.sh"   22 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes       3306/tcp            nauseous_wright
```

I'd like to add a function to my bash profile which returns the IP Address of my running MySQL image. The problem is that the docker inspect command seems to capture the IP Address only if you provide the ContainerID (which is not static)

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' e9b37fc68787425606fbaf0a558
```

Is there any option which allows me to do something like that:

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' mysql
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run container with name

```
docker run --name mysql ...
```

Now, uses inspect and use the name instead of ID

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' mysql
172.17.0.2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

give a name to your container with

`docker run --name my_mysql...`

, and then look for it with

`docker ps -q --filter="name=my_mysql"`

will give you the id, and then you know how to do it

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!